# How to close individual React Native emulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, emulation

I'm running my app on a React Native emulator. I was originally emulating just the iPhone 6, and then added an iPhone 6 Plus emulator. When you add a second emulator it keeps the first one open. How do you close one of them while keeping the other open? Basically I want to de-select one of the emulators shown in the photo below:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode device's emulator behaves like any other window, so you just have to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+W on the one you want to close, it's like closing just one window of any other application.

And if you want to know more about Mac keyboard shortcuts, [here's a link!](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)